# Bearer Token for REST API in SpringBoot without Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, rest, bearer-token

I have a simple REST API which is a GET service and doesn't require any user login to consume, but I want to protect it using Bearer Token, when I research on this in internet it's been showed that I need to implement bearer token only after user logs in and authenticated. Is there a way in springboot where I can generate a token for my API and give it to client and client calls my API with that and the program validates the same and provides response?

Answer (score 0):

You have the OAuth2TokenGenerator available in [Spring Authorization Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-generator).